# Why does this happens in passing an array?

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, jsp

I'm trying to pass the array of values from a function in `.js` file to `.jsp` file using `document.formname.action` but its creating the array index out of bound.

My `.js` file (note this line: `document.detailsview.action=" "`):

```
function savetheChanges(count)
{
    var kkot1=new Array();
    var iitemcode1=new Array();
    var dropdown11=new Array();
    var billno=document.getElementById("billno").value; 
    for(var i=0;i<count;i++)
    {   
        var selec = document.getElementById("sel"+i);
        dropdown11[i] = selec.options[selec.selectedIndex].value;
        kkot1[i]=document.getElementById("kot"+i).value;
        iitemcode1[i]=document.getElementById("itemcode"+i).value;
        //var dummydrop=dropdown1[i];
        alert(i+" "+dropdown11[i]);
        //var mydropp=dropdown11[i];        
    }
    document.detailsview.action="BillCB.jsp?method=" + "11" + "&billno="+billno+"&itemStatus1="+dropdown11+ "&kot="+kkot1+ "&itemcode="+iitemcode1;
  }
```

`BillCB.jsp` (`method11`):

```
case 11:
gotMethod = true;   
billdetails_be.billno = Integer.valueOf(request.getParameter("billno"));
String[] kotCbb=request.getParameterValues("kot");
String[] itemCbb=request.getParameterValues("itemcode");
String[] statCbb=request.getParameterValues("itemStatus1");
System.out.println("IN AVAILABLE:Size of KOT array is :" +kotCbb.length);
System.out.println("IN AVAILABLE:Size of ITEM array is:"+itemCbb.length);
System.out.println("IN AVAILABLE:size of STATUS array is:"+statCbb.length);
```

Output in console is:

```
IN AVAILABLE:Size of KOT array is :19
IN AVAILABLE:Size of ITEM array is:19
IN AVAILABLE:size of STATUS array is:1
```

Comment: where is the exception, paste the stacktrace.

Comment: no error.but the size of Status array is 1.thats the problem

Comment: Could you past the stacktrace from which you concluded that you get an array ondex out of bound exception?

Comment: its displaying in my Myerrorhandler.jsp